# Rails ActionController::TestCase no route matches for custom named nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am trying to write test cases for a nested resource and I am seeing the following error:

```
Error:
    test_should_get_single_budget_link(BudgetlinkControllerTest):
    ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:budget_id=>980190962,    :action=>"show", :controller=>"budgetlink"}
    test/functional/budgetlink_controller_test.rb:5:in `test_should_get_single_budget_link'
```

My routes.rb looks like:

```
Simplebudget::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => "home#index"

resources :budgets do
    resources :transactions
    resources :budgets, :controller => :budgetlink
end

resources :classifications
resources :periodicities

end
```

My test looks like the following:

```
test "should get single budget link" do
    get :show, 'budget_id' => budgets(:one).id
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal assigns(:budgetlink).primary, "Budget1" 
    assert_equal assigns(:budgetlink).secondary, "Budget2" 
end
```

I believe it is the fact that I have configured the routes to use the resource name "budgets" instead of budgetlinks and Rails has no way in my current test to recognize the budget route.  How can I configure my test to recognize my remapped route?

Not sure if it is necessary but figured it couldn't hurt.  Here is the controller code:

```
class BudgetlinkController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 

def show
    @budgetlink = Budgetlink.find(params[:primary], params[:secondary])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html   #index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @budgetlink}
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the issue.  I was on the correct track, I was not writing the test in such a way that it would generate a GET to the correct resource/route.

```
test "should create budget link" do
     assert_difference('Budgetlink.count') do 
       post :create, :budget_id => budgets(:one).id,
                     :budgetlink => { :primary => budgets(:one).id,
                                      :secondary => budgets(:two).id}
    end      

    assert_redirected_to budget_path(assigns(:primarybudget))
    assert_equal 'Budget link created.', flash[:success]
 end
```